# Need unique dateformatter for single number (day & month)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, date-format, dateformatter

Input: `9(Wed).12(Dec).2020`

Day and month are represented by one number

I need date formatter for above input date string

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
func getDateFrom(_ str:String) -> Date? {
    let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "dd(EEE).MM(MMM).yyyy"
    let date = dayTimePeriodFormatter.date(from: str)
    return date
}
```

and call it `getDateFrom("9(Wed).12(Dec).2020")`

Comment: If my input is `9.12.2020`, then formatter is `dd.MM.yyyy` ?

WIll it work for 9.1.2020. I mean single number for Month also?

Comment: yes it will ... it will make difference when you convert a date to string but not vice versa

Comment: you should always try everything you need to ask about a run will tell you more than an experience

Comment: This is wrong . Besides the dateFormat you should always set the locale to en_US_POSIX when parsing a fixed date format and for dates without a time you need also to set the DateFormatter calendar property to avoid a failure when parsing daylight savings transition dates when there is no midnight

Comment: Btw this will create a new DateFormatter every time you call this method. Bad solution and it might fail